# multi-select box without ctrl-click

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, multi-select

I am using the code which is written in this stackoverflow post

[How to avoid the need for ctrl-click in a multi-select box using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641729/how-to-avoid-the-need-for-ctrl-click-in-a-multi-select-box-using-javascript)

it is recommended also in many other articles, to do multiple selection without ctrl-click.

the code:

```
$('option').mousedown(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).prop('selected', !$(this).prop('selected'));
    return false;
});
```

The problem is that the code is not working on FireFox 31.0. 
you can try it using the following link

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/techfoobar/xQqbR/)

does anybody know a work around for this problem :)

Comment: im a big fan of the multiselect plugin for jqueryui http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget, this will also allow people to filter, and have a 'select all' option

Comment: Thank you for your comment, actually it is better for me to find the problem without using a new library :)

Comment: have you try clicking on choices using mouse's scroll button? :D it doesn't need CTRL to be pressed

Comment: actually, this is a requirement to just use the left mouse button :)

Comment: I tested this. There is no error. It just does not work.

Comment: there is no error, but the functionality is not correct, you should be able to select multiple options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code works in firefox 31.0,IE 10 and crome 36.0.1985.143. But it dose not work   well if CTRL keys  is used also.

```
 $('select').bind("click", function (event, target) {

        event.preventDefault();
        var CurrentIndex = event.target.selectedIndex==undefined? $(event.target).index(): event.target.selectedIndex
        var CurrentOption = $("option:eq(" + CurrentIndex+ ")", $(this));
        if ($(CurrentOption).attr('data-selected') == undefined || $(CurrentOption).attr('data-selected') == 'false') {
            $(CurrentOption).attr('data-selected', true);
        }
        else {
            $(CurrentOption).prop('selected', false).attr('data-selected', false);
        }

        $("option", $(this)).not(CurrentOption).each(function (Index, OtherOption) {
            $(OtherOption).prop('selected', ($(OtherOption).attr('data-selected') == 'true') ? true : false);
        });
         return false;
    });
```

Comment: You can test if the ctrl or meta key is pressed. Also I believe it is `.on` and no longer `.bind`

Comment: thank you for your comment,
There is a simple problem but i dont know where.
if the select started with some selected options like this:
<select multiple="multiple">
    <option id="1" selected = "selected">Opt</option>
    <option id="2" selected = "selected">Opt</option>
    <option id="3">Opt</option>
    <option id="4">Opt</option>   
</select>
and now if you try to select other options, it always clears the already selected ones.

Comment: @user3584625 I have used a custom attribute data-selected to track its state so you need to maintain that attribute also. So when you are making the option already selected, set the attribute also to true.

Comment: It did not work in IE 11. Can't select multiple values