# How to select multiple values from dropdown?I am using Bootstrap css version 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to select the multiple values from the dropdown.I am using bootstrap css.

This is my dropdown code:

```
  <select multiple class="dropdown-menu">
        <option value="monday">Monday</option>
        <option value="tuesday">Tuesday</option>
        <option value="wednesday">Wednesday</option>
        <option value="thursday">Thursday</option>
        <option value="friday">Friday</option>
        <option value="saturday">Saturday</option>
        <option value="sunday">Sunday</option>
    </select>
```

By using the above code i can select multiple options by using CTRL key,but i don't want use ctrl key and i need to select multiple values.

Is it possible to do that with jquery,javascript?

One more thing like Can i select not more than two or three values is it possible?

Many thanks in advance....

Comment: There is a great plugin for this [Bootstrap-multiselect](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect) that lets you create a dropdown with checkboxes to select. Might be worth looking into! =)

Comment: If you really don't want to use Ctrl key to select multiple  items, then [bootstrap multiselect plugin](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/) might be able to help you. Check out it's demo.

Comment: Thanks for the response and suggestion,but i don't want use any check boxes.

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to do without ctrl click.

```js
$('option').mousedown(function(e) {
e.preventDefault(); 

$(this).prop('selected', $(this).prop('selected') ? false : true);

alert($("#mySelect :selected").length);//select option selected count
//if($("#mySelect :selected").length==2)
//some stuff
   
return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="multiple" id="mySelect">
    <option id="1">Option</option>
    <option id="2">Option</option>
    <option id="3">Option</option>
    <option id="4">Option</option>
</select>
```

[See this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641729/how-to-avoid-the-need-for-ctrl-click-in-a-multi-select-box-using-javascript)

Comment: ,Thanks for the response,but i don't need any pop-up or alerts.Can we do that without alert.

Comment: put it in comments. Just checking purpose here I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.dropdown-menu option').mousedown(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).prop('selected', !$(this).prop('selected'));
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response@Sadikhasan,one small doubt like can we select min 1 and max 4.

Answer (score 0):

you can use plugins for dropdowns like "Multiselect" / "chosen"
1. http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/ 
2. https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/