# A proper multi selection -select, that works in IE and crossplattforms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, multiple-select

I've been looking for a multi-selection select that works in any IE-version (yeah), that also doesn't render new elements which mimic a select.

Most of the solutions I've found on SO didn't work in IE duo the fact that IE allways acts as if you target the SELECT-element and not the OPTION-element. Even e.target on window will say it targets the SELECT-element.
I've tried work-arounds on several solutions but didn't manage to find one that works in all browsers: 
[How to avoid the need for ctrl-click in a multi-select box using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641729/how-to-avoid-the-need-for-ctrl-click-in-a-multi-select-box-using-javascript)

So I made my own solution which isn't perfect. But it does work. I will list some issues and my questions further down

**This is my example**: [JS-FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Salmin/L13kavmc/)

```
// Array which holds selected categories
var selected = $("select.multiSelect").val() || [];


$(".multiSelect").bind("click", function(e) {

  // If found in array, remove it, else add it.
  var found = $.inArray(this.value, selected);
  if (found >= 0) {
    var index = selected.indexOf(e.target.value);
    selected.splice(index, 1);
  } else {
    selected.push(this.value);
  }

  // Update the visual of the select
  $(".multiSelect").val(selected);

});
```

**1. The main question:** If I already have a few categories selected and try to select another one. The whole selection blinks, which is annoying. Can this be avoided with css or js?

2. I tried the solution in IE, Chrome iPhone (works nativly) and an Android (works nativly). Can someone predict a plattform or case where it won't work?
3. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Are you looking for an element that works in "ANY IE-version" or "ALL BROWSERS"? can you be more specific on what browsers and versions?

Comment: Currently none of the previous found answers work in IE 11. (And older). I was looking for a solution that works in all browsers, but ended up building my own, but I did run into an issue (question 1).

Comment: <select multiple> works in almost ALL browsers, but requires a shift key press. Why not using that?

Comment: Check [ChosenJS](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

Comment: Can't get old people to hold shift / ctrl. Trying to work around it =/

Comment: @jmb.mage I'm trying to avoid adding extra kbs of js to the project. Even tho ChosenJS is small and pretty