# Jquery select option as selected on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I Keep the two selected fields as select using a JavaScript/jquery function, if I pick a different language.

I know that STRG + mouselick works but I do not want that.

```
<fieldset class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="bg">Bulgarisch</option>
        <option value="da">Dänisch</option>
        <option value="de" data-type="edit" selected="selected">Deutsch</option>
        <option value="en" data-type="edit" selected="selected">Englisch</option>
        <option value="et">Estnisch</option>
        <option value="fi">Finnisch</option>
    </select>
</fieldset>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j280fhuu/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid the need for ctrl-click in a multi-select box using Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641729/how-to-avoid-the-need-for-ctrl-click-in-a-multi-select-box-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mousedown` event

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/Anshul_Sinha/j280fhuu/4/)

Like this:

```
$('option').mousedown(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).prop('selected', $(this).prop('selected') ? false : true);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this :

```
$("#language_selection_audio").change(function(){
    $(this).find("option[data-type='edit']").prop('selected', true)
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j280fhuu/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#language_selection_audio').val(['de', 'en']); // Pass an array, for multiple selections
   $('#language_selection_audio :selected').attr('data-type', 'edit'); // Add custom attribute
});
```

[JS Fiddle Here.](https://jsfiddle.net/0o9ed6sk/)

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this will help; Try it!
I can't understand clear what you want.

```
var $input = $('#language_selection_audio');

function markLangs( langs ){
    $input.find('option').removeAttr('data-type').attr('selected',false);

    $.each( langs, function( i ){
         $input.find('option[value=' + langs[i] + ']').attr('data-type','edit').attr('selected',true);              
    });             
};

$input.on('change', function(){
    markLangs( $(this).val() );
});
```

see ya.