# select multiple options without holding CTRL

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to make `LeftMoust` & `SmartDevices` clicks automatically multi-select the options without the need of holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, Using HTML and CSS only?

```
<select multiple>
    <option>Value1</option>
    <option>Value2</option>
    <option>Value3</option>
    <option>Value4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8641765/244811

Comment: What is `LeftMoust` & `SmartDevices`? I'm not aware of these objects in HTML or CSS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid the need for ctrl-click in a multi-select box using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641729/how-to-avoid-the-need-for-ctrl-click-in-a-multi-select-box-using-javascript)