# Select all option if item-all was selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have something like this:

```
<select multiple>
  <option value="all-item" selected>All</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

What I need:

1. After init only "All" is selected (done).
2. If the customer selected other options, "all-items" should be unselected.
3. If the customer has select e.q 2 options and after that will select "all-item", an only first option should be select and another should be unselected.

I tried to do it like that:

```css
$("#all-item").on('focus', function() {
    $("#selecty option").each(function(){
       $(this).attr("selected", "selected");
    });
});
```

```html
<select multiple>
  <option value="all-item" selected>All</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

but doesn't work.
Anybody can help?

Comment: Selecting multiple options vary in different operating systems and browsers. Because of the different ways of doing this, and because you have to inform the user that multiple selection is available, it is more user-friendly to use checkboxes instead. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641729/how-to-avoid-the-need-for-ctrl-click-in-a-multi-select-box-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

I made it with vanilla JS, because you don't need JQuery for that :

```js
function handleChange(element) {
  if(element.value === 'all-item') {
    const options = [...element.options];
    for (let opt of options) {
      if (opt.value !== '' && opt.value != 'all-item') { opt.selected = true; } 
      else { opt.selected = false; }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
option {
  padding: 12px;
}
```

```html
<select id="select" multiple onchange="handleChange(this)">
  <option value="">Chose an option</option>
  <option value="all-item">All</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

### EDIT

To unselect every other option :

```js
function handleChange(element) {
  if(element.value === 'all-item') {
    const options = [...element.options];
    for (let opt of options) {
      if (opt.value === 'all-item') { opt.selected = true; } 
      else { opt.selected = false; }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
option {
  padding: 12px;
}
```

```html
<select id="select" multiple onchange="handleChange(this)">
  <option value="">Chose an option</option>
  <option value="all-item">All</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP wants the value `all-items` to be a possible outcome of his select. Not a way to select everything.

Comment: Then he doesn't need to ask a question, he simply needs to return `all-item` like an option.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check if `all-item` is selected with `.is(':selected')` when the user selects anything, and unselect anything else with `.attr('selected',false)` :

```js
$('select').on('change',function(){
  if($('option[value="all-item"]',this).is(':selected')){
    $('option:not([value="all-item"])',this).attr('selected',false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple>
  <option value="all-item" selected>All</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @trichetriche  For windows: Hold down the control (ctrl) button to select multiple options ; For Mac: Hold down the command button to select multiple options

Comment: :D Thank you @CodeIt, what doesn't work is clicking on "all". Not selecting several values.

Comment: @trichetriche it's not supposed to. `all-items` is a valid value for his select, as I understand it.

Comment: Then as I answered you, in this case there's no need for a question, just return the `all-item` value like it's any option.

Comment: @trichetriche The question was how to unselect anything else when `all-items` is selected.

Comment: After reading it ten times, I think I see the same thing as you. I will make an edit to my answer in this case ! Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Wait, to do that you just have to click on all-items without holding ctrl, so yeah, I'm sticking to my original statement, you don't need to ask a question !

Comment: @trichetriche It's always better to do it without holding ctrl. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48302925/select-all-option-if-item-all-was-selected/48303069#comment83591352_48302925)